# I have installed a worldpay library in codeigneter but having issue with create order

Tags: php, worldpay

I have installed a Worldpay library it's working in core PHP but I try to use in CodeIgniter I get the error

```
Class 'Worldpay' not found
```

because I didn't use

> namespace Worldpay

if I use namespace in ci then its giving error.

```
Class 'Worldpay\CI_Controller' not found
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Worldpay are horendously expensive and their service security was not best practise (md5 hashing of identifying variables) when I last looked (2016)

Comment: @Martin I really hate Wordpress and yet more than 50% of the web runs on it. Let's keep it constructive and help OP :)

Comment: i have installed from github https://github.com/worldpay/worldpay-lib-php

Comment: They are using 
<?php
namespace Worldpay;
?>

Comment: But i can not do this in CI

Comment: Did you install it manually, or did you use Composer? *from GitHub* is a bit vague.

Comment: i have installed it manually

Comment: They are going to update there urls. Thats why i am new version for this

Comment: Find solution 

we need to use class of namespace

$worldpay = new Worldpay\Worldpay("site_key");

Comment: @Loek I do agree (and also hate WP) hence this was a gentle comment, rather than a dictation

Comment: OP: Try `namespace \Worldpay;`, any luck?

Comment: @martin i have used $worldpay = new Worldpay\Worldpay("site_key");

And its work fine now
Thanks

Comment: @loek i do agree with you i also hate wordpress but still as you said 50% of the web runs on it.